# Time machine error-1

Tags: time-machine, backup, error

How can I solve the problem - The backup disk image “/Volumes/Time Capsule de xx/MacBook Pro xx.sparsebundle” could not be accessed (error -1).

Comment: Welcome. Someone might be able to guess the issue, but if you don't get quality answers, feel free to review our guide on [ask] and consider editing in a little details like what OS you are running, and if you have tried any of the [general Time Machine troubleshooting steps listed here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3275)

Answer (score 1):

In Time Capsule go to "Disk" then "File Sharing".  Make sure "Share disk over the internet using Bonjour" is not checked. Don't know why but it caused this problem for me.